# Redirect folder to subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, .htaccess, redirect

I want to have 2 Ruby on Rails applications on a domain.

The first one is running at `example.com`; I have done that with .htaccess (with RewriteRule to `example.com:12001`)

I want the other one to be in a subdomain, like `blog.example.com`. So I created a subdomain, and in the file .htaccess I redirect to `example.com:12002`.

Everything is working fine, but if I go to address `example.com/blog`, I am not redirected, and I see in browser the contents of blog folder in public_html:

```
Index of /blog

    Parent Directory
```

I would like to go to the second application(`blog.example.com`) when the url is `example.com/blog`. How could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution depends on how your hosting provider implements multi-subdomain mapping.  Some offer a control panel so that you can register your subdomains and point each to a separate subdirectory in your file space.  Some will just map `*.yourdomain.zzz` to the document root for `yourdomain.zzz`, and from your description, this is what is happening for you.  In this case you need to decode the **HTTP_HOST** variable and route on that.  But you also need to stop your rewrite rule looping so that `sub1.yourdomain.zzz` doesn't get mapped to yourDocRoot/sub1/sub1/sub1...`

If you wanted to process **sub1** and **sub2** subdomains, then you would do this with a rule in you top level like this:

```
RewriteBase  /
RewriteCond  %{ENV:REDIRECT_INSUB} !=1
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}          (sub1|sub2)\.yourdomain\.zzz
ReweriteRule ^(.*)                 %1/$1         [L,E=INSUB:1]
```

Search for **[.htaccess] HTTP_HOST** to see lots of variants of this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I searched more and managed to fix it. I do have separate subdirectories for each subdomain. Writing this in `blog/.htaccess` seems to work: `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(blog\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com:12002/$1 [P,QSA,L]`

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you must replace `http://blog.example.com/whatever_or_empty` to `http://www.example.com/blog/whatever_or_empty` in your HTML hrefs.

`blog.example.com` although a sub domain, is a different URL. i.e. when a RewriteRule does a rewrite to another URL an external redirect will occur. This will reflect in the browser. Be a temporary `redirect(302(the default))` or `permanent redirect(301)`.

So, using url rewriting to change the link `http://blog.example.com/` to `http://www.example.com/blog/` is useless.

---

Although, you can achieve this using [Apache Module mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html).

The Apache Proxy Modules has these:

> - mod_proxy: The core module deals with proxy infrastructure and configuration and managing a proxy request.
> - mod_proxy_http: This handles fetching documents with HTTP and HTTPS.
> - mod_proxy_ftp: This handles fetching documents with FTP.
> - mod_proxy_connect: This handles the CONNECT method for secure (SSL) tunneling.
> - mod_proxy_ajp: This handles the AJP protocol for Tomcat and similar backend servers.
> - mod_proxy_balancer implements clustering and load-balancing over multiple backends.
> - mod_cache, mod_disk_cache, mod_mem_cache: These deal with managing a document cache. To enable caching requires mod_cache and one or both of disk_cache and mem_cache.
> - mod_proxy_html: This rewrites HTML links into a proxy's address space.
> - mod_xml2enc: This supports internationalisation (i18n) on behalf of mod_proxy_html and other markup-filtering modules. space.
> - mod_headers: This modifies HTTP request and response headers.
> - mod_deflate: Negotiates compression with clients and backends.

---

You need at-least `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` modules enabled for the proxy to work:

you should have lines similar to these in your apache's `conf` file:

```
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
```

use this in your **`Virtualhost`** of `http://www.example.com`

```
ProxyPass /blog http://blog.example.com
ProxyPassReverse /blog http://blog.example.com
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On

<Proxy *>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

**Definitions:**

> - [ProxyPass <sup>Apache Docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass).
> - [ProxyPassReverse <sup>Apache Docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse).
> - [ProxyRequests <sup>Apache Docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyrequests).
> - [Proxyvia <sup>Apache Docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyvia).

---

You can also use a cache with `mod_cache`: `mod_cache`.
For more on caching, refer here: [mod_cache <sup>Apache Docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_cache.html).

---

Also disable index views indexes by setting this:

```
options -indexes
```

Add a `index` to the folder `blog`.

Comment: I don't think you understood my problem. If I had some simple html files inside blog folder, it would have worked, because blog.example.com and example.com/blog are pointing to this same folder. But I have Ruby on Rails applications, which are situated in rails_apps folder. Both public_html folder and blog subfolder contain a single file only: `.htaccess`

Comment: @TrueSoft I have understood your problem. That is why I suggested you the proxy solution. You also have to set up a `virtualhost` for `blog.example.com` so that you Ruby files will work.

Comment: I can't find file httpd.conf. Anyway, I think there is a solution much simpler, such as writing some redirects, but I'm not so familiar with the syntax.

Comment: @TrueSoft try it your way :).

Comment: Thinking Monkey, this guy uses a shared service hosting provider.  You entire approach is only valid _if_ you have root access to the Apache config.  This just isn't the case here.

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey, The prob is that OPs don't give enough info in their original Qs.  Rewrite answers can be _very_ different depending on whether the person has root access to Apache or is just limited to `.htaccess` files.  Maybe that should be our first response if it isn't immediately obvious.  :-(

Comment: @TerryE I agree. Sometimes they do not even provide it when asked for. :(

Comment: @TerryE In the question I _did_ mention that I used the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @True,Sorry this was more of a side-exchange between a couple of answers. Apache recommends that you use the server/vhost configs and only use .htaccess as a point of last resort, but as I has discussed \([here](http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/article-59)\) on my blog, people resort to `.htaccess` files because their hosting service only offers this.  In these cases there is no point in giving a system/vhost solution.  :-)