# SubDomain.DOMAIN.COM to remain as such in browser address bar - .htaccess / mod_rewrite

Tags: linux, .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.DOMAIN\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.DOMAIN\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://DOMAIN.com/FolderName/$1 [L]
```

If I type in SubDomain.DOMAIN.COM it redirects me to DOMAIN.COM/Folder/ fine, but I do not want the url in the browser address bar to change to DOMAIN.COM/Folder/ but remain as SubDomain.DOMAIN.COM.

Any clues to this.

Comment: you either (1) need a frame / iframe ; OR (2) need the [P] flag in rewrite and mod_proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.DOMAIN\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.DOMAIN\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://DOMAIN.com/FolderName/$1 [L]
```

When a rewriterule points to a domain, an explicit redirect will occur. By default a 302 redirect (temporary redirect).

I suggest you to use the [`P`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p)(proxy) flag. For this to work, `mod_proxy` should be enabled.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.DOMAIN\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://DOMAIN.com/FolderName$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.DOMAIN\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://DOMAIN.com/FolderName/$1 [L,P]
```

Also remember to set-up a [`ProxyReverse`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) directive.

```
Context:    server config, virtual host, directory
```

So, you cannot have a `ProxyReverse` in `.htaccess`.

Taken directly from: [Proxying Content with mod_rewrite <sup>Apache Docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html).
    Consider using either *ProxyPass* or *ProxyPassMatch* whenever possible in preference to mod_rewrite.

Visit this for how to *ProxyPass*: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189447/858515

Comment: Does including Options FollowSymLinks in the httpd.conf help?

Comment: @Jean yes, but tat would only matter if you have symbolic links in your folders.

Comment: Now another issue I want to capture SubDomain using php, tried this `echo ['$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']']` but it gives me http://DomainName/FolderName/ and not SubDomain.DomainName.com

Comment: @Jean That will not be possible through `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`as you are proxying it to `domainname.com`. You can although capture it in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` if you rewrite it properly.

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey You cannot use proxy and get original $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] value -- PHP is executed as DomainName/FolderName and only proxied to SubDomain.DomainName.com

Comment: @kupson My previous comment is based on OPs another question as well.

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey If Subdomain and Domain servers share single machine proxy isn't necessary. It will add latency and make two requests instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

Look at RewriteRule [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

```
Absolute URL

If an absolute URL is specified, mod_rewrite checks to see whether the
hostname matches the current host. If it does, the scheme and hostname
are stripped out and the resulting path is treated as a URL-path.
Otherwise, an external redirect is performed for the given URL.
```

So - try to use direct filesystem path:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.DOMAIN\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.DOMAIN\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /path/to/domain.com/DocumentRoot/FolderName/$1 [L]
```

Comment: /path/to/domain.com/DocumentRoot/FolderName/ is http://DomainName.com/FolderName.  So I would write it as 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /FolderName/$1 [L]?

Comment: You could try it. I don't know for sure if it would work. Safe bet is a full filesystem path like /var/www/server/folder/.